# Vectorised argument for a function in R. The function gives out multiple data frames, whereas I'd like it to output only one

Tags: r

I'd like to compute trimmed mean for each trimming proportion alpha, and then see which trimming proportion gives the minimal variance of the trimmed means, when Bootstrap simulations of size N=200 are applied. The problem that I have, is that when I try to create a data frame of column1 = mean and column2 = variance, the code that I wrote creates each output of mean and variance as separate data frame, so I cannot look up the trimming proportion and trimmed mean which have the minimal variance.

The function gives out "data.frame" 9 times. I guess it's because the alpha argument is vectorized.  The code:

```
 tmean_var <- function(n,N,alpha){
      set.seed(1)
      data <- rnorm(n)
      data_aug1 <- c(data, -data)
      data_aug2 <- c(data, 2 * median(data) - data)
      est <- data.frame()
      tmean <- replicate(N, {
      sample <- base::mean(sample(x = data[(round(alpha*n)+1):(n-round(alpha*n))],
                                    size = n-2*round(alpha*n), replace = TRUE))
    })
      
    mean <- base::mean(tmean)
    var <- var(tmean) * (n-2*round(alpha * n))
    df <- data.frame(mean = mean, var = var)
    class(df)
    }
    f <- Vectorize(tmean_var, vectorize.args = "alpha")
    f(n,N,alpha)
```

How could I make the output to be one dataframe not nine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  Rather than try to use `Vectorize()` on a function that doesn't inherently take vector arguments, you could just use `sapply()` and `lapply()` across the values of `alpha` you provide as below:

```r
tmean_var <- function(n,N,alpha){
  set.seed(1)
  data <- rnorm(n)
  data_aug1 <- c(data, -data)
  data_aug2 <- c(data, 2 * median(data) - data)
  est <- data.frame()
  tmean <- lapply(alpha, function(a){replicate(N, {
    sample <- base::mean(sample(x = data[(round(a*n)+1):(n-round(a*n))],
                                size = n-2*round(a*n), replace = TRUE))
    })
  })
  
  mean <- sapply(tmean, mean)
  var <- sapply(seq_along(tmean), function(i)var(tmean[[i]]) * (n-2*round(alpha[i] * n)))
  df <- data.frame(mean = mean, var = var, alpha=alpha)
#  class(df)
}

out <- tmean_var(100, 200, c(.1, .2, .3))
out
#>         mean       var alpha
#> 1 0.10555709 0.8066377   0.1
#> 2 0.06868891 0.8331401   0.2
#> 3 0.21791984 0.9024612   0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>